# Creating additional virtual hosts on xampp

Tags: apache, xampp

I've been following this guide on setting up addition virtual hosts for my freelance work on my Linux machine.

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-apache-virtual-hosts-on-arch-linux

I've followed this guide exactly and I can get the end result as shown in the last picture in the guide.

However when trying to use any relative link, linking to a new page i get this error.

[Object not found](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aDKWk.png)

And I just can't figure out why.... its frustrating me no end. I've searched the net and these forums and cannot find the answer....

could someone give me a steer in the right direction?